# JPA Criteria Tutorial

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0

I've been trying to find a JPA Criteria API tutorial but haven't been much successful. Do you know about any for beginners? I'd like to start using it in an Java5/Maven app to build complex search queries.

Comment: Correlation coefficient between off-topic and usefulness == 1.0

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/) article is a very good one on this topic, actually the best one I've found so far **online**, even better than the [Chapter 23 Using the Criteria API to Create Queries](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) from the Java EE 6 tutorials (that contains some mistakes).

Comment: @HDave Oracle's EE7 link to the Criteria API has changed to [https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm#GJITV](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm#GJITV)

Answer (score 14):

Examples of common queries are [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria)

All examples are in this form:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

// Query for a List of objects.
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root e = cq.from(Employee.class);
cq.where(cb.greaterThan(e.get("salary"), 100000));
Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
List<Employee> result = query.getResultList();
```

---

If you are also considering other technologies you should seriously consider [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/). Main advantages over criteria include shorter code, good readability and similar syntax to regular sql.

Example QueryDSL code here:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
List<Person> persons = query.from(person)
  .where(
    person.firstName.eq("John")),        
  .list(person);
```

Comment: your first example throws "No explicit selection and an implicit one could not be determined " exeption

Comment: `.where(` the bracket opened here does not close.

Answer (score 7):

Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java Persistence API
http://books.google.com/books?id=j84hdeHH2PYC

This is the source I find the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.altuure.com/2010/09/23/jpa-criteria-api-by-samples-part-i/