# Search engine implementation

Tags: java, search-engine, implementation

I'm trying to implement Search Engine. I have web application that displays list of articles in DataGrid. In DB I have table with article data (title, creation date, last update date, owner etc.) In UI I have search component (with date pickers, drop boxes etc.) i.e. I want to search all articles with owner = 'admin' and creation date >12/16/2010. How would you implement such search engine on back-end? By the way back-end written on java.

May be someone knows some articles or books?

Comment: use [apache lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and save yourself a **lot** of time.

Comment: Please define *search* - do you want to *get* all articles that qualify for the query or do you want to *search inside* those articles? If first - dynamic query builder, if second - dynamic query builder plus text search (lucene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thought's may sometimes be the best: JPA Criteria API is often used to dynamically build complex search queries.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997070/jpa-criteria-tutorial) where they point to some tutorials for further investigation/reading

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for a production system, I would recommend you take a look at some of the free Information Retrieval Libraries the internet has to offer, such as Apache Lucene. It is quite hard to implement such a system yourself, but if you really want to it can be a rewarding experience. In the later case, I recommend you take a look at some introductionary literature on Information Retrieval.

One great book on this topic I can recommend is "Introduction to Information Retrieval" by Christopher D. Manning et. al. It's available for free as a PDF here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html

Cheers,
Johannes