# How to eliminate "unchecked" warnings when using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I do a lot of querying with javax.persistence. And Java forces me to either suffer warnings or @Suppress them, neither of which feels right.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Area> getArea(Province province) {
    Query qry = em.createQuery("Select c from Area c where c.province = ?1");
    qry.setParameter(1, province);
    return qry.getResultList();
}
```

How do I eliminate the warning in the above code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using JPA annotations, use [`TypedQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) instead of `Query`:

```
TypedQuery<Area> qry = em.createQuery(
    "Select c from Area c where c.province = ?1", Area.class);
```

Comment: I would also suggest the OP to use named parameters

Comment: If I do that I get a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Query to TypedQuery<Area>`. The `em.createQuery` will only generate a plain Query as a result.

Comment: Check the second parameter in the createQuery(String, class) method. You are passing the type.

Comment: Ok, got it, you need to add the `Area.class` to the createQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Criteria API to avoid this. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3997070/49489) for info on how to use it.

Comment: +1, however in this case it is not necessary to use the Criteria API, but the code of the OP can be ported to TypedQuery that uses generics and requires less rework.

Comment: The convoluted way in which the Criteria API forces you to writes queries makes my head hurt. It's an exercise in masochism.